# Weight painting using Auto Rig Pro on Blender 2.8

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, auto-rig-pro

I need help with painting weights on a rig made with auto rig pro. I cant find the correct vertex groups for the bone I'm painting. There's an arm twist offset and an arm stretch vertex groups to paint on. Which of these is the arm really?

Theres an arm twist offset vertex group
[image: Theres an arm twist offset vertex group]

Also an arm stretch vertex group
[image: Also an arm stretch vertex group]

Here you can see the fk controller driving the left arm bone
[image: Here you can see the fk controller driving the left arm bone]

So which of these is the correct vertex group to paint on? I see the fk controller for the shoulder is driving the c_arm_fk.L bone, but it doesn't show up in the list of vertex groups for the weight painting on the arm. This is my first time using auto rig pro and I'm used to rigging in Maya.

Comment: Thank you Duarte!

Comment: Hey Maito. I've created an Auto Rig Pro chatroom for discussing the addon on this site. My guess is that not many people use it, so I don't know how useful it will be. I also don't know if you will be able to join it without at least 20 reputation. If this is not the case, can someone please let me know? Because this is my current understanding, and so its what I've been telling everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, You are supposed to weight paint based on the bones that are in layer 31. It should look like this when you view it.

[image: Where the bones are]

Artell has provided the character Mike in his manual for weight paint reference.You can check it out in here : http://lucky3d.fr/auto-rig-pro/doc/auto_rig.html#how-to-paint-the-weights

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip about which layer has the bones to paint on, MercuryRising. I always found the old layer system a bit cryptic because the contents would never have any labels.